# How to fix broken utf-8 encoding in Python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

My string is `Niá»‡m Bá»“ TÃ¡t (Thiá»n sÆ° Nháº¥t Háº¡nh)` and I want to decode it to `Niệm Bồ Tát (Thiền sư Nhất Hạnh)`. I see in that site can do that http://www.enderminh.com/minh/utf8-to-unicode-converter.aspx

and I start to try by Python

```
mystr = '09. BÃ¡t NhÃ£ TÃ¢m Kinh'
mystr.decode('utf-8')
```

but actually it is not correct because original string is utf-8 but the string show is not my expecting result.

Note: it is Vietnamese character.

How to resolve that case? Is that Windows Unicode or something? How to detect the encoding here.

Comment: looks like it was encoded as `utf-8` but interpreted as `latin-1`.

Comment: `>>> "Niệm Bồ Tát (Thiền sư Nhất Hạnh)".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')`
`'Niá»\x87m Bá»\x93 TÃ¡t (Thiá»\x81n sÆ° Nháº¥t Háº¡nh)'` pretty close...

Comment: @ch3ka, its actually cp1252, a superset of latin-1

Comment: @BillLetson "Niệm Bồ Tát (Thiền sư Nhất Hạnh)".encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/cp1252.py", line 15, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,errors,decoding_table)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 23: character maps to <undefined>
It is not cp1252

Comment: @sepdau yes, it is. Use .decode('cp1252', errors='ignore') and you will get the mangled string exactly. Whatever program mangled your string in the first place ignored errors, which is why you can't get the ề character back even with the accepted answer modified to use cp1252.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm not sure what you can do with these kind of data, but for your example in your original post, this works (Python 3.x):

```
>>> mystr = '09. BÃ¡t NhÃ£ TÃ¢m Kinh'
>>> s = mystr.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
>>> s
'09. Bát Nhã Tâm Kinh'
>>> print(s)
09. Bát Nhã Tâm Kinh
```

Comment: The encoding used to mangle this data was most likely cp1252, so using that instead of latin-1 will allow you to recover more (though not all) of the characters. Ni�m B� Tát (Thi�n sư Nhất Hạnh) vs Niệm Bồ Tát (Thi�n sư Nhất Hạnh)

Comment: I know it in python3 but how about in python2?

Comment: @sepdau My example was with Python 2.7 on Linux :)

Comment: @multani it not work when I decode >>> mystr = 'Niá»‡m Bá»“ TÃ¡t (Thiá»n sÆ° Nháº¥t Háº¡nh)'
>>> s = mystr.decode('utf8').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u2021' in position 4: ordinal not in range(256)
>>>

Comment: @sepdau I don't know where your data are coming from, but it seems to be pretty broken, and unless you really know how it was generated from, you probably only have to do by trial/error until either you found the right "weird" encoding used or enough sets of encoding/decoding combinations that work (like "utf-8/latin1/utf-8", or "utf-8/cp1252/utf-8", etc.) I'm not sure there's one solution to fit all your use cases, sadly.

Comment: Could you maybe update your answer so that it works in python3?

Comment: For Python3, you only need the latter part: `s = mystr.encode('latin1').decode('utf8)`

Answer (score 31):

The only thing that helped me with broken cyrillic string - https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy

This module fixes pretty much everything and works much better than online decoders.

```
>>> from ftfy import fix_encoding
>>> mystr = '09. BÃ¡t NhÃ£ TÃ¢m Kinh'
>>> fix_encoding(mystr)
'09. Bát Nhã Tâm Kinh'
```

It can be easily installed using `pip install ftfy`

Comment: if I use "from ftfy import fix_encoding" although it helped me to fix the problem that I faced regarding UTF-8, my code takes too much time to give me the result

Comment: It worked for me to fix encoding problems in html using lxml libs. Amazingly worked in the first try. Thanks

Comment: @rodrigorf thanks should go to lib creator =) Star repo

Comment: @DimaRostopira:  +1 for ftfy. It is **amazing**. Thank you for mentioning it. I would never have found it otherwise. And yes, I did send a thank you to the creator already. ;-)

Comment: This library is astounding. It Just Works™, and far better and faster than my hacks would have. Kudos to the lib creators, and for you, Dima, for telling us about it!

Comment: Thank you. I lost about a whole day looking for some answer like yours.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

`str.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')`

You're encoding the string in ASCII format / ignoring the errors and decoding in UTF-8. This may remove the accents, but it's one approach.

Answer (score 0):

The correct method in python 3.9.6 is:

```
"string".encode('utf-8').decode('latin-1')

"string".encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

So, you can use:

```
'09. BÃ¡t NhÃ£ TÃ¢m Kinh'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

and the output is:

```
>>> '09. BÃ¡t NhÃ£ TÃ¢m Kinh'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
'09. Bát Nhã Tâm Kinh'
```