# Only half of my CSV is encoded

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I'm importing a cvs file into pandas and when I do the first few names are encoded correctly then further down the accents turn back into symbols. It's a pretty large file with almost 200 names. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue.

```
import sys
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
#%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.pylab import rcParams
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter( "ISO-8859-1" )( sys.stdout.detach() )
rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 15, 6


data = pd.read_csv('IndNames.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
pd.get_option("display.max_rows")
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', False)
pd.set_option('display.height', 500)
data.align(data, axis=1)
print(data.head(n=182))

Ex: José
    JosÃ©
```

Edit: ftfy does not work with dataframes

Edit1: I can't figure out the problem when I save it to a csv file everything is normal then when I use `pd.read_csv` to use it again it's unencoded.

Comment: See [**`ftfy`**](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to detect and fix wrongly encoded unicode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python How to fix broken utf-8 encoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491448/python-how-to-fix-broken-utf-8-encoding)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter( "UTF-8" )( sys.stdout.detach() )
```

Simple fix and I don't know why it didn't work before when I tried it but this did the trick

Comment: If anyone can explain why this worked I would appreciate it